# Append new files to the already indexed files using Lucene

Tags: lucene

From the database, some data are taken and is indexed and stored using lucene.

Later, some more data is added to the db and I need to index those newly added data only and append to the existing indexed files.

Can you explain with a program ?

Comment: When asking questions on Lucene, please always specify version being used.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is **incremental indexing** and this is less on indexing side and more on selection approach of data ( target documents ) from database.

You need to make your SQL `SELECT` query to flexible enough to use a column that identifies newly added / updated rows.

That column is usually a `DATE` column i.e. something like - `LAST_ADDED_DT` , `LAST_UPDT_DT` so you can fetch records added / updated in last x days , x hours etc.

e.g. on DB2 like , `WHERE DATE(LAST_UPDT_DT) >= CURRENT DATE - 2 DAY` will give your records updated in last two days etc.

and then use `updateDocument(...)` method of Lucene writer instead of `addDocument(...)` since `updateDocument(...)` will add documents if a document is a new document and will update if document already exists.

So this approach takes care of updated existing rows as well as new rows.

Lucene creates new files or appends to existing files is not your headache then, Lucene will organize files as per its settings and structure for that version.

You should open your writer in `OpenMode.CREATE_OR_APPEND` mode.

Hope this helps !!

Comment: Yes, it is incremental indexing. I can take the last added files alone and don't bother about that. The problem is with appending that files with the already indexed files. So can you help with a sample program for appending that newly indexed file with already indexed file ?

Comment: so writer.addDocument takes a document as the argument,but updateDocument method takes a term. I have addDocument in my program currently which I want to convert to updateDoc. How to convert the document to a term so it can be fed to updateDocument method ? any help appreciated